# Elasticsearch : Document count is lesser than the number of document indexed

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing via bulk api (provided by `org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient`), the number of document I index is **381942** but when I use the _count api of elasticsearch it shows lesser count, that number varies each time I index but it is always less (e.g. **238632, 279241, 282325** etc). When I try to refresh then the count increases by 1. What's going on?

Note: I have checked the response and **there are no failures**, as well.

Java Code :

```
BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
for (FileEntity fileEntity : entities) {
        File file = entityToFile(fileEntity);
        Map<String, Object> dataMap = objectMapper.convertValue(file, Map.class);
        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(INDEX, TYPE, file.getId().toString())
                .source(dataMap);
        bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);

}

 try {
       BulkResponse response = restHighLevelClient.bulk(bulkRequest);
       System.out.println(response.getItems().length+" : "+response.hasFailures());
     } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
            e.getDetailedMessage();
        } catch (java.io.IOException ex){
            ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
```

ES query

```
{   "query": { "match_all": { }} }
```

**Update** : Adding index stats

```
{
"_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"_all": {
    "primaries": {
        "docs": {
            "count": 242217,
            "deleted": 84242
        },
        "store": {
            "size_in_bytes": 81527525
        },
        "indexing": {
            "index_total": 381942,
            "index_time_in_millis": 21265,
            "index_current": 0,
            "index_failed": 0,
            "delete_total": 0,
            "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
            "delete_current": 0,
            "noop_update_total": 0,
            "is_throttled": false,
            "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "get": {
            "total": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "exists_total": 0,
            "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
            "missing_total": 0,
            "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0
        },
        "search": {
            "open_contexts": 0,
            "query_total": 10,
            "query_time_in_millis": 0,
            "query_current": 0,
            "fetch_total": 0,
            "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
            "fetch_current": 0,
            "scroll_total": 0,
            "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
            "scroll_current": 0,
            "suggest_total": 0,
            "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
            "suggest_current": 0
        },
        "merges": {
            "current": 0,
            "current_docs": 0,
            "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "total": 5,
            "total_time_in_millis": 13133,
            "total_docs": 232660,
            "total_size_in_bytes": 60188264,
            "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
            "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
            "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
        },
        "refresh": {
            "total": 122,
            "total_time_in_millis": 31415,
            "listeners": 0
        },
        "flush": {
            "total": 0,
            "periodic": 0,
            "total_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "warmer": {
            "current": 0,
            "total": 96,
            "total_time_in_millis": 2
        },
        "query_cache": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "total_count": 0,
            "hit_count": 0,
            "miss_count": 0,
            "cache_size": 0,
            "cache_count": 0,
            "evictions": 0
        },
        "fielddata": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "evictions": 0
        },
        "completion": {
            "size_in_bytes": 0
        },
        "segments": {
            "count": 38,
            "memory_in_bytes": 390123,
            "terms_memory_in_bytes": 344621,
            "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 26752,
            "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
            "norms_memory_in_bytes": 7296,
            "points_memory_in_bytes": 7494,
            "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3960,
            "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
            "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
            "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
            "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
            "file_sizes": {}
        },
        "translog": {
            "operations": 381942,
            "size_in_bytes": 113256156,
            "uncommitted_operations": 381942,
            "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 113256156,
            "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
        },
        "request_cache": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 3495,
            "evictions": 0,
            "hit_count": 5,
            "miss_count": 5
        },
        "recovery": {
            "current_as_source": 0,
            "current_as_target": 0,
            "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
    },
    "total": {
        "docs": {
            "count": 242217,
            "deleted": 84242
        },
        "store": {
            "size_in_bytes": 81527525
        },
        "indexing": {
            "index_total": 381942,
            "index_time_in_millis": 21265,
            "index_current": 0,
            "index_failed": 0,
            "delete_total": 0,
            "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
            "delete_current": 0,
            "noop_update_total": 0,
            "is_throttled": false,
            "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "get": {
            "total": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "exists_total": 0,
            "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
            "missing_total": 0,
            "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0
        },
        "search": {
            "open_contexts": 0,
            "query_total": 10,
            "query_time_in_millis": 0,
            "query_current": 0,
            "fetch_total": 0,
            "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
            "fetch_current": 0,
            "scroll_total": 0,
            "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
            "scroll_current": 0,
            "suggest_total": 0,
            "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
            "suggest_current": 0
        },
        "merges": {
            "current": 0,
            "current_docs": 0,
            "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "total": 5,
            "total_time_in_millis": 13133,
            "total_docs": 232660,
            "total_size_in_bytes": 60188264,
            "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
            "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
            "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
        },
        "refresh": {
            "total": 122,
            "total_time_in_millis": 31415,
            "listeners": 0
        },
        "flush": {
            "total": 0,
            "periodic": 0,
            "total_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "warmer": {
            "current": 0,
            "total": 96,
            "total_time_in_millis": 2
        },
        "query_cache": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "total_count": 0,
            "hit_count": 0,
            "miss_count": 0,
            "cache_size": 0,
            "cache_count": 0,
            "evictions": 0
        },
        "fielddata": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "evictions": 0
        },
        "completion": {
            "size_in_bytes": 0
        },
        "segments": {
            "count": 38,
            "memory_in_bytes": 390123,
            "terms_memory_in_bytes": 344621,
            "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 26752,
            "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
            "norms_memory_in_bytes": 7296,
            "points_memory_in_bytes": 7494,
            "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3960,
            "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
            "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
            "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
            "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
            "file_sizes": {}
        },
        "translog": {
            "operations": 381942,
            "size_in_bytes": 113256156,
            "uncommitted_operations": 381942,
            "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 113256156,
            "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
        },
        "request_cache": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 3495,
            "evictions": 0,
            "hit_count": 5,
            "miss_count": 5
        },
        "recovery": {
            "current_as_source": 0,
            "current_as_target": 0,
            "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
    }
},
"indices": {
    "test_index": {
        "uuid": "uhSpFQr-Qk2yb4_vvA8siQ",
        "primaries": {
            "docs": {
                "count": 242217,
                "deleted": 84242
            },
            "store": {
                "size_in_bytes": 81527525
            },
            "indexing": {
                "index_total": 381942,
                "index_time_in_millis": 21265,
                "index_current": 0,
                "index_failed": 0,
                "delete_total": 0,
                "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
                "delete_current": 0,
                "noop_update_total": 0,
                "is_throttled": false,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            },
            "get": {
                "total": 0,
                "time_in_millis": 0,
                "exists_total": 0,
                "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
                "missing_total": 0,
                "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
                "current": 0
            },
            "search": {
                "open_contexts": 0,
                "query_total": 10,
                "query_time_in_millis": 0,
                "query_current": 0,
                "fetch_total": 0,
                "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
                "fetch_current": 0,
                "scroll_total": 0,
                "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
                "scroll_current": 0,
                "suggest_total": 0,
                "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
                "suggest_current": 0
            },
            "merges": {
                "current": 0,
                "current_docs": 0,
                "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total": 5,
                "total_time_in_millis": 13133,
                "total_docs": 232660,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 60188264,
                "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
            },
            "refresh": {
                "total": 122,
                "total_time_in_millis": 31415,
                "listeners": 0
            },
            "flush": {
                "total": 0,
                "periodic": 0,
                "total_time_in_millis": 0
            },
            "warmer": {
                "current": 0,
                "total": 96,
                "total_time_in_millis": 2
            },
            "query_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total_count": 0,
                "hit_count": 0,
                "miss_count": 0,
                "cache_size": 0,
                "cache_count": 0,
                "evictions": 0
            },
            "fielddata": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "evictions": 0
            },
            "completion": {
                "size_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "segments": {
                "count": 38,
                "memory_in_bytes": 390123,
                "terms_memory_in_bytes": 344621,
                "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 26752,
                "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "norms_memory_in_bytes": 7296,
                "points_memory_in_bytes": 7494,
                "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3960,
                "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                "file_sizes": {}
            },
            "translog": {
                "operations": 381942,
                "size_in_bytes": 113256156,
                "uncommitted_operations": 381942,
                "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 113256156,
                "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
            },
            "request_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 3495,
                "evictions": 0,
                "hit_count": 5,
                "miss_count": 5
            },
            "recovery": {
                "current_as_source": 0,
                "current_as_target": 0,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            }
        },
        "total": {
            "docs": {
                "count": 242217,
                "deleted": 84242
            },
            "store": {
                "size_in_bytes": 81527525
            },
            "indexing": {
                "index_total": 381942,
                "index_time_in_millis": 21265,
                "index_current": 0,
                "index_failed": 0,
                "delete_total": 0,
                "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
                "delete_current": 0,
                "noop_update_total": 0,
                "is_throttled": false,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            },
            "get": {
                "total": 0,
                "time_in_millis": 0,
                "exists_total": 0,
                "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
                "missing_total": 0,
                "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
                "current": 0
            },
            "search": {
                "open_contexts": 0,
                "query_total": 10,
                "query_time_in_millis": 0,
                "query_current": 0,
                "fetch_total": 0,
                "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
                "fetch_current": 0,
                "scroll_total": 0,
                "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
                "scroll_current": 0,
                "suggest_total": 0,
                "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
                "suggest_current": 0
            },
            "merges": {
                "current": 0,
                "current_docs": 0,
                "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total": 5,
                "total_time_in_millis": 13133,
                "total_docs": 232660,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 60188264,
                "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
                "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 104857600
            },
            "refresh": {
                "total": 122,
                "total_time_in_millis": 31415,
                "listeners": 0
            },
            "flush": {
                "total": 0,
                "periodic": 0,
                "total_time_in_millis": 0
            },
            "warmer": {
                "current": 0,
                "total": 96,
                "total_time_in_millis": 2
            },
            "query_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total_count": 0,
                "hit_count": 0,
                "miss_count": 0,
                "cache_size": 0,
                "cache_count": 0,
                "evictions": 0
            },
            "fielddata": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "evictions": 0
            },
            "completion": {
                "size_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "segments": {
                "count": 38,
                "memory_in_bytes": 390123,
                "terms_memory_in_bytes": 344621,
                "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 26752,
                "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "norms_memory_in_bytes": 7296,
                "points_memory_in_bytes": 7494,
                "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 3960,
                "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                "file_sizes": {}
            },
            "translog": {
                "operations": 381942,
                "size_in_bytes": 113256156,
                "uncommitted_operations": 381942,
                "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 113256156,
                "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
            },
            "request_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 3495,
                "evictions": 0,
                "hit_count": 5,
                "miss_count": 5
            },
            "recovery": {
                "current_as_source": 0,
                "current_as_target": 0,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide your sample code or generated query?

Comment: in a query, you have passed any condition?

Comment: can you share you code ?

Comment: Is it possible that some documents have the same ID? That would explain why you have less documents since some would be overridden.

Comment: @Val nope, all ids are unique, primary key in DB

Comment: You mean `file.getId().toString()` is a DB primary key?

Comment: @val yes, it is

Comment: @NishantSaini There are no failures, I have checked

Comment: And you're sure you're checking the same index or alias?

Comment: @Val only one index is there

Comment: Side question: you're sending 381942 docs in a single bulk request or in several  batches? how big are those docs, resp. the batches?

Comment: @val I have tried with batch size of 10000, 50000, 100000 and each results in different count

Comment: Have you nested documents?

Comment: @LeBigCat No, it is a simple flat document with 5 fields

Comment: And dumb question, but you're sure you're hitting the same cluster as the bulk loader?

Comment: @val I am testing in my local machine and there is only one cluster.

Comment: Can you show how you're sending your `match_all` query?

Comment: @val localhost:9200/test_index/_doc/_count

Comment: you sure your indexation is over? You didnot change default config settings, like refresh timer?

Comment: @LeBigCat Indexation is over, I didn't change the default config, I even manually refreshed and flushed

Comment: Maybe do a simple program to check if some documents are missing in your index. Maybe some of them are used by another process or somethingelse.

Comment: It was my mistake, I didn't add order by in my postgres query, so the order was inconsistent.